# Redirecttoaction is taking back to the loginpage

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

I have a loginpage where the user may select the forgot password link and the user is then allowed to change the password. When the new password is genearated/changed by the user the user should be logged in instead of taking back to the login page. For this, I am using redirectiontoaction to the the method ( i.e. dashboard in my case). But the control is returning back to the login page. 
Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult LogOn(Login.LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        //some code here and in the end redirect as shown below
         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Conroller1", new { Area = "" });
     }
```

The login page then has this in the address bar of the browser.

```
http://localhost:8888/Login/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FConroller1%2FIndex
```

This is my web.config

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" timeout="35"/>
    </authentication>
```

How to fix this? Please guide me through.

Comment: have you set the authentication cookie?

Comment: Matt - It worked like a charm. However, I need to know what is the use of FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, true); This is what I did  string user = Session["UserName"].ToString();
           
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user, true);

Comment: once the user has updated their password you can just manually log them in once you have confirmed their credentials. FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, true) is the same as checking a "remember me" box, FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, false) would mean you need to log back in after your session exipires.